# How to create a reference to a child item in XML using PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have a XML file, generated by WinServer 2019 (GPO export). I'd like to create a reference to a child item, to the one, which contains the name of the AD groups:

```
        <q1:UserRightsAssignment>
          <q1:Name>SeNetworkLogonRight</q1:Name>
          <q1:Member>
            <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-9</SID>
            <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS</Name>
          </q1:Member>
```

The command, I tried:

```
[xml]$GpoXml = Get-GPOReport -name $param1 -ReportType Xml

$Object3 = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.UserRightsAssignment) {
    if ($p.Name -ne $null) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Name" = $p.Name
            "Value" = $p.Member.Name
        }
    }
}
```

For the $p.$Name I got "SeNetworkLogonRight" as Name, but for the Value I got "System.Object[]" answer.
Why is that? How should I create a reference to get the value of the Member/Name item?

Many thanks!

Update:

The full block:

```
> <q1:UserRightsAssignment>
>           <q1:Name>SeNetworkLogonRight</q1:Name>
>           <q1:Member>
>             <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-9</SID>
>             <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">NT
> AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS</Name>
>           </q1:Member>
>           <q1:Member>
>             <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-11</SID>
>             <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">NT
> AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users</Name>
>           </q1:Member>
>           <q1:Member>
>             <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-32-544</SID>
>             <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">BUILTIN\Administrators</Name>
>           </q1:Member>
>           <q1:Member>
>             <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">Admin</Name>
>           </q1:Member>
>         </q1:UserRightsAssignment>
```

Comment: In your XML sample, are these the only child elements of `UserRightsAssignment`?

Comment: No, updated the post with the full block. Thanks

Comment: Each `UserRightsAssignment` has multiple members, so you need to loop over these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *multiple* `<Member>` child elements, which causes PowerShell to return them as an *array* (of type `[object[]` ([`System.Object[]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object%5B%5D)).

Accessing the `.Name` property on this array - due to PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) - then returns the array of `<Name>` grandchild elements, across all `<Member>` elements.

Also note that you must access the `.InnerText` property of `.Name` in order to get only the element's *text* in this case (because the element also has *attributes*).

You need to:

- either: create a `[pscsustomobject]` instance *for each member*.

```
$Object3 = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.UserRightsAssignment) {
    if ($p.Name) {
      foreach ($m in $p.Member) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $p.Name
            Value = $m.Name.InnerText
        }
      }
    }
}
```

- or: if you want to stick with a *single* `[pscustomobject]` per privilege and want a *string* representation of the *array* of member names so that you can export the objects to a CSV file, for instance, you'll need to come up with a *custom stringification* of the array; in this example, `/` is used as the separator:

```
$Object3 = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.UserRightsAssignment) {
    if ($p.Name) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $p.Name
            Value = $p.Member.Name.InnerText -join '/'
        }
    }
}
```